# Implicit type conversion: JSON_VALUE() vs TRY_CAST(JSON_VALUE())

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a generic link table to link records we have, with records of another database. I could create a link table for every table in the source database. However since there is support for `JSON` now I thought that maybe this was a good use case to investigate that support.

So instead of creating multiple tables called `Link{SourceTableName}` I create one table with a `GUID` to represent the Id on our side and an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column to represent the `JSON` containing the primary key of the source table. I save the primary key as `JSON` because I have to support composite primary keys. If I want the data in the source table I can `JOIN` the `JSON` column with `JSON_VALUE` together with the primary key in the source table.

Since `JSON_VALUE` returns an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` I will get an implicit type conversion when the primary key of the source table is not an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` which is to be expected. If I however wrap that `JSON_VALUE` with a `TRY_CAST` that implicit conversion is no longer necessary. I decided to do that but I got curious if there was any performance loss due to the extra function call. And here's where things turned odd...

Below is a comparison of a simple `SELECT *` on the source table vs a `SELECT * joined on TRY_CAST(JSON_VALUE())` vs a `SELECT * joined on JSON_VALUE()`.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

I have created a sample query which reproduces the issue.

```
CREATE TABLE [#Link] (
    [Id] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Link_Id] DEFAULT(NEWID()),
    [LinkId] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Link] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY])
ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [#Customer] (
    [Id] CHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(200) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY])
ON [PRIMARY]

DECLARE @i INT = 0
WHILE @i < 20
BEGIN
    WITH seed AS (
        SELECT (@i * 32767) + 1 AS n
        UNION ALL
        SELECT n+1 FROM seed WHERE n+1<=(@i * 32767) + 32767
    )
    INSERT INTO
        [#Customer]
    SELECT
        RIGHT('0000000'+CAST([n] AS VARCHAR(7)),7)
        ,RIGHT('0000000'+CAST([n] AS VARCHAR(7)),7)
    FROM
        seed OPTION(maxrecursion 32767)
    SET @i = @i + 1
END

INSERT INTO
    [#Link] ([LinkId])
SELECT
    [value] FROM OPENJSON((SELECT [Id] FROM [#Customer] FOR JSON PATH))


SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM [#Customer]

SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM [#Customer]
JOIN [#Link] ON [#Customer].[Id] = TRY_CAST(JSON_VALUE([#Link].[LinkId], '$.Id') AS char(7))

SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM [#Customer]
JOIN [#Link] ON [#Customer].[Id] = JSON_VALUE([#Link].[LinkId], '$.Id')

SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [#Customer]

SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [#Customer]
JOIN [#Link] ON [#Customer].[Id] = TRY_CAST(JSON_VALUE([#Link].[LinkId], '$.Id') AS char(7))

SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM [#Customer]
JOIN [#Link] ON [#Customer].[Id] = JSON_VALUE([#Link].[LinkId], '$.Id')

DROP TABLE [#Customer]
DROP TABLE [#Link]
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see there is a difference between the execution plan of the first `JSON_VALUE()` query and the second `JSON_VALUE()` query. I'm no hero in the deciphering of execution plans but just the fact that there is a difference is interesting.

There is a warning present complaining about the implicit type conversion which is present on both execution plans. This must be what is causing the difference in execution plans, because when changing the data type of `[#Customer].[Id]` to NVARCHAR(7) the execution plans of a TOP 10 and a TOP 100 remain the same.

I know that CONVERT_IMPLICIT is a performance killer but I wouldn't have expected to see a difference between a TOP 10 and a TOP 100. Since the second query is faster than the first, it's obviously possible for the first to be as fast. Why isn't the query optimizer always choosing the second execution plan or am I asking too much?

Comment: Why not use the JSON_VALUE() function in the OPENJSON function when you are first creating #Link? That way you can just join directly on #Link.Id which will be much faster.

Comment: @Jon In reality I have to support composite primary keys. Unless I am not understanding your suggestion correctly, it's not possible to support this without saving as JSON. I will update the question.